# Execute a Jquery function from browser to debug?

Tags: jquery, firefox

is it possible to execute a jquery function in a firefox window? For example, let's say I want to do:

```
$.fn.colorbox.resize();
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by **firefox window**?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? executing it from firebug for example?

Comment: I'm trying to debug my website and I want to execute code that would do 'something' to the website to see the effects. I have a feeling that some of the code I have may be 'timed' wrong which is why I was wondering if I could just execute any jquery string and see what it does to the page. Thanks

Comment: hello Py, yes - from firebug for example

Comment: I have, just now learned how to use the console, however by simply inputting $.fn.colorbox.resize();, I get 'undefined'.

Comment: Well the console outputs the result of the function, so if resize() returns nothing, undefined is the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the console, as long as jQuery is loaded on the page you can use jQuery in the console to test. If its not loaded on the page you can use the below bookmarklet to load it first

```
javascript:var%20s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src',%20'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);alert('thank you for using jquery!');void(s);
```

**[Original Bookmarklet link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet)**

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the console. Well, when I try to input '$.fn.colorbox.resize();' inside it - I get 'undefined' in the console.

Comment: Hmm, in order to resize the colorbox dont you have to call resize on the element like so? `$('.element').colorbox.resize();` ? Im not very familiar with colorbox tbh. I just know I use the above method when Im testing out jQuery selectors on random pages.

Comment: Not when I do it from a normal JS inside the website - maybe when I do it in the console I do. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to show "action" I would just put a border around something:

```
$(myselector).css("border","red solid 3px");
```

OR if that messed with layout:

```
$(myselector).css('background-color","lime");
```